# XAML binding against Auto-Implemented properties?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Is it possible to using XAML data binding to a model with Auto-Implemented properties?

```
class ClassA
{
  // pseudo code.
  int Width { get; set{ NotifyPropertyChange("Width");} }
}


//XAML
<textBox width="{Binding Path=Width,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile as-is. You can't have any code in the getter or setter for auto-implemented properties.

Comment: Added a comment to point out that this isn't suppose to compile.

Comment: To get this to bind, you need to make the property public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-properties don't have a half auto mode. It needs to either be an auto-property with nothing extra:

```
int Width { get; set; }
```

or a fully expanded property with a backing store that can have additional code added to it, like change notification:

```
int _width;
int Width
{
  get { return _width; }
  set
  {
    _width = value;
    NotifyPropertyChange("Width");
  }
}
```

If you use auto-properties you can still bind to them but you're giving up change notification, so any changes you make to the property from code won't show up in the UI. In general any object being used for data binding should include change notification and so should not use auto-properties.

Answer (score 2):

i interprete Autoproperty this way.

```
class ClassA
{
  int Width { get; set;}
}
```

**Yes** one-way binding to view is always possible.

Twoway binding require `NotifyPropertyChange("propertyname");` only if you want that changes in one modell element cause automatic update of the gui or other observers.

There is tool that can autogeneretates INotifyPropertyChange implementation for you: [notifypropertyweaver](http://github.com/SimonCropp/NotifyPropertyWeaver).

Update

There is also a INotifyPropertyChange-Free altenative for two way binding described in [code-magazine article "INotifyPropertyChanged Is Obsolete"](http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0907101) using the free lib [updatecontrols on codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/updatecontrols)

Comment: Why would twoway binding require `INotifyPropertyChanged`? `INotifyPropertyChanged` is about delivering the observer pattern so that even something binding in OneWay mode will be notified of a change.  It has nothing to do with the directionality of binding.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones i totally agree (+1) and updaged my post

Comment: Its better but you still seem to be confused about roles of the binding mode and the observer pattern.  For example what if you have just one way binding and something else modifies the property, say polling update from a server?  NotifyPropertyChanged is needed if you want to observe changes __regardless__ of whether that change as a result of two way binding.  Whether two way binding is being used or not is __irrelevant__ to the observation of a property change.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not a Auto-implemented property, in fact it will probably not compile.

To implement this you would need to either implement a full backing-store property or use aspects to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged so that you can keep your Auto property clean.

Comment: It's a mix of Auto-Implemented property, and the INotifyPropertyChanged XAML binding, to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use xaml binding with Auto properties. But as said, the property illustrated is not an Auto property.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do this?